# ios11 [ImageManager] Unable to load image data

Tags: ios

in xcode9/ios 11, when I request PhAsset, xcode sometimes log this info :

```
[ImageManager] Unable to load image data, /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/104APPLE/IMG_4807.JPG
```

On all iOS 10.x.x devices/simulators everything is fine.

here is my method

```
PHImageRequestOptions *option = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
option.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeFast;
option.networkAccessAllowed = YES;

return [[PHCachingImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:size contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:option resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
    BOOL downloadFinined = ![[info objectForKey:PHImageCancelledKey] boolValue] && ![info objectForKey:PHImageErrorKey];
    if (downloadFinined && completion) {
        completion(image, info);
    }
}];
```

Comment: And what is your problem exactly?

Comment: thanks, I dont want xcode log this info.  I had fix it, because I used a wrong size，w:800,h170,    when I change the size to w:170 h:170,it's ok

Comment: I am seeing same problem since upgrade to iOS 11.  Small size images load fine, but if I request full size about 20% fail to load, with log message as you show.

Comment: My question is just the opposite of yours, when small size  fail to load, just because the proportion of size is wrong